# Windows 10 access to CentOS

Tags: linux, windows, centos

How can a windows 10 user access the CentOs Linux 7.1.1503 over samba server? Windows 7 and 8 users are able to access but Windows 10 user.

Comment: The setup should be identical to the actions you took on those Windows 7 and Windows 8 installations.

Comment: There might be wrong with the actions I take with the installations for windows 7 or 8...may I know the proper way to install it with windows 7?